# How to --watch uncompressed files (without Webpack)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have worked code, which is built in /dist by webpack, for developming that is slow to wait for updating/building in dist/ folder and get result form it also. there is good "webpack-dev-server --port=4200" command but I have expressJS. How I can get updating result fast after run project. Maybe It is possable via webpack or not:

```js
/////////////////////package.json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "dev": "concurrently nodemon ./src/index.ts \"tsc -w -p ./src\" ",
    "start": "ng build && concurrently nodemon ./src/index.ts \"tsc -w -p ./src\" ",
    "build": "ng build --watch",
    "build:watch": "\"tsc -w -p ./src\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },

//////////////////////index.ts
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { json, urlencoded }from 'body-parser';

var app : any = express();

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname + '/../dist')));
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(join(__dirname + '/../dist/index.html'));
});

console.log('3000!! ', 3000);
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I tried just to include ./src folder - app.use(express.static(resolve(__dirname, '../src'))); res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.html')); but it is not working:

Help Please

```
packaje.json
dist
assets
src - app
    - index.html
    - index.ts
```